# Asynchronous uuid generation in node

Tags: node.js, performance

I began using `--trace-sync-io` to detect synchronous calls in my code and noticed the `node-uuid` package is making a lot of them via the crypto module. Is synchronous `uuid` generation expensive enough to warrant refactoring to use async? If so, what is the appropriate approach or package to do this?

Comment: Which actual calls in node-uuid are you making?

Comment: Profile to find out. [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) 
The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.

Comment: uuid.v4() without options. I don't see an option for a callback anywhere.

Comment: My MBP generates almost 400K UUID's a second. Just sayin'

Comment: I think I'm asking for general guidance about performance in node from those with experience. Prior to seeing this common use of synchronous uuid generation, my mental model for node performance was "absolutely no synchronous calls per request."

Comment: @RavTrav I think that should be "absolutely no _long running_ synchronous calls". Things like `JSON.parse()` are also synchronous, but hardly ever a bottleneck.

Comment: Is the `--trace-sync-io` flag reporting actual synchronous I/O or is it just reporting a synchronous function call that takes longer than xx ms to execute?

Comment: It also depends upon what exactly you're trying to do with the uuid too if you want to replace it.  One can coin a very cheap UUID with a counter, a `Math.random()` result and a timestamp that works for a lot of uses - depending upon what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my mental model for node performance was "absolutely no synchronous
>   calls per request."

This is usually true for blocking tasks that meaningfully stop work. You wouldn't want to synchronously wait for a 400ms API call or reading or writing to disk (hence FS having sync and async options). As noted above, node-uuid is benchmarked pretty quickly, so optimizing for asynchronicity is likely a waste of developer and program time.